# Why doesn't SQL find my declared variables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to insert data in a local declared table. The table has an `IDENTITY` primary key, so when I want to insert a value with a specific primary key I have to use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON`.

However the `SET` statement doesn't find my local table.

```
DECLARE @testtable TABLE (
    [row_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT @testtable ON

INSERT INTO @testtable VALUES (234)
```

But I get the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near '@testtable'.

And tip:

> Incorrect syntax near '@testtable'. Expecting '.', ID or QUOTED_ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **INSERT into an identity column is not allowed on table variables.**

Use temporary table instead:

```
CREATE TABLE  #testtable(
    [row_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY );

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #testtable ON;

INSERT INTO #testtable(row_id) VALUES (234);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/XWREWR55213)**</kbd>

Comment: Great LiveDemo as well (I've been looking for a SQL-Server)